# Transfer data from Zapier authentication to trigger

Tags: node.js, zapier

I am working on a Zapier app and there is a tenant id (integer) that is retrieved during authentication that I need to use in a trigger. What is the correct way to do this?

I have tried using global, bundle.authData and storing the data in a module, but nothing seems to work consistently. The best has been when I stored the data in global, but it is inconsistent, out of six calls to the trigger the tenant id may only be valid twice, the other four times it will be returned as undefined.

In the case of global I am writing the data during authentication:

```
const test = (z, bundle) => {

  return z.request({
      url: URL_PATH + ':' + URL_PORT + '/v1/auth',
      params: {
          username: bundle.authData.username,
          password: bundle.authData.password
      }
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      throw new Error('The username and/or password you supplied is incorrect.');
    } else {
      global.GLOBAL_tenant = response.json.tenant;
      // ...
    }
}
```

And then attempting to read the data back in the trigger:

```
const processTransactions = (z, bundle) => {

  let jsonAll = [];
  let tenant  = global.GLOBAL_tenant;

  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    (function loop() {
    // ...
```

I also tried adding the dat to 'bundle.authData', this was the recommendation that Zapier made when I contacted them, but the tenant id that I added during the authentication:

```
bundle.authData.tenant = response.json.tenant
```

Is not available when I try to retrieve it in the trigger. Only the 'username' and 'password' are present.

I am new to Zapier and node.js so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning fully qualified name like `bundle.authData.tenant = response.json.tenant`, please use something like `tenant = response.json.tenant` and this statement should be enclosed in a `return` statement preferably. The `bundle.authData` qualifier is automatically applied by Zapier.

`global` variables should be avoided. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

`global` isn't going to work because your code runs in multiple lambda executions and state isn't stored between them. Plus, global implies it would be the same for all users, which probably isn't what you want.

Instead, I'd check out [session auth](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#session), which will let you store extra fields during your test by creating a computed field and returning values for it from `sessionConfig.perform`. Then it'll be stored in the auth object, next to the username and password.

Separately, you may want to consider whatever code is in `processTransactions`. Either you can return them all and they'll deduped on our end, or you're doing a bunch of extra computation that is better [dehydrated](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#dehydration). That's just a guess on my part though, so feel free to ignore this part.